# how to overwrite name in wtforms Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

new.html

```
{{ form.particular(name='particular[]') }}
```

I tried the above code to assign a name in my input field but I got a  following error. But if i add a class or id replacing name
(for eg:    {{ form.particular(id='particulars') }} ) it works but doesn't work for name just outputs the following error:

builtins.TypeError
TypeError: html_params() got multiple values for keyword argument 'name'

Any Solution. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

When you define a Form:

```
class WebForm(FlaskForm):
    particular = StringField('some_description')
```

the then you have a field whose `name=particular`, this is underlying function of wtforms. So when you try to do `form.particular(name='particular[]')` it gives the multiple values error, since you cannot redefine the name in the jinja2 template.

You overwrite the name in one of two ways (note both are server side before jinja2 rendering occurs):

1) statically: i.e. define a new name:

```
class WebForm(FlaskForm):
    particular_new = StringField('some_description')
```

2) dynamically: i.e. a wrap function creates an amended static form:

```
def WebForm(new_name):
    class TempForm(FlaskForm):
        pass
    setattr(TempForm, new_name, StringField('some_description'))
    return TempForm()
# will create a WebForm with attribute name of 'new_name' as StringField
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is sending form data via render template, then just put the variable name in the template between {{ var_name }} and in the code use this var_name in the return render template function.

Comment: No I don't need to send data via render template. I just need to add my custom name in input field like <input type="text" name="particular[]">

Comment: When and where does this custom name become known and available? Can I assume you still are using a function render template?